# How is sum() used to merge lists

Tags: python

I am learning trees in python, which I was showed with these functions to build a tree:

```
def tree(label, branches=[]):
    return [label] + list(branches)

def label(tree):
    return tree[0]

def branches(tree):
    return tree[1:]
```

There is a function that can extract all the nodes of a tree into a list:

```
def all_nodes(tree):
    return [label(tree)] + sum([all_nodes(b) for b in branches(tree)], [])

T = tree(1, [tree(2, [tree(4), tree(5)]), tree(3, [tree(6), tree(7)])])
print(all_nodes(T))
# >>> [1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7]
```

You can see that this worked very well, but I got confused how `sum()` is used here.

I know that a list can be added to another list:

```
print([1] + [2]) # >>> [1, 2]
```

But I can't make it work by using `sum()`:

```
a, b = [1], [2]
print(sum(a, b))
# >>> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
print(sum([a, b]))
# >>> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list
```

In the `tree` function, how did `sum()` work to merge all the lists?

Comment: Re-read the example you're trying to copy: you're missing the second argument. `sum((a, b), [])` works just fine.

Comment: Notice `sum([[1] , [2]], [])` will work.

Comment: @jonrsharpe beat me to it; if you want to understand this better, make yourself familiar with `reduce` http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html

Comment: @JosepValls Ok, this works, but why? Python docs does not explained this very clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum` operates on a sequence of elements, such as `sum([1, 2, 3])` (producing `6`) or `sum([ [1], [2] ], [])` (producing `[1, 2]`).  There is an optional second argument, the `start` value.  For instance, `sum([1, 2, 3], 10)` would start the summation at 10, providing `16`.  `start` defaults to `0`: if you're summing non-numeric objects, you have to provide a compatible `start` value.

When you give it `sum(a, b)`, the list `a` becomes the list of arguments.  What `sum` did was to (correctly) iterate through the items of that list, adding them to the `start` value you provided.  The logic is something like this:

```
result = b
for element in a:
    result = result + element
```

Thus, the first thing you tried to do was `result = [2] + 1`.  Remember, that first argument is a *sequence* of the things you want to add up.  The most trivial change (although not the most readable) that would let your attempt work is

```
sum([a], b)
```

which produces `[2, 1]`, since `b` is the starting value.

Does that explain what happened?

Comment: It does not. You mentioned `sum([ [1], [2] ])` (producing [1, 2]), well, that's what I showed that it did not work there

Comment: Thanks; I left out the starting value -- the default is `0`, which kills the example as I typed it.  I also caught a typo.

Comment: the key thing here is that `sum([[1], [2]])` is actually doing `sum([[1], [2]], 0)`

Comment: Thanks, I got your point. Basically I need the starting point (second variable) to be an empty list, so that the sub list in [a. b] can be added to. If I do not set the secondary variable, the default is 0, which is an int, and can not be added to a sub-lists like [1] and [2].

Comment: @asongtoruin No, I think the the key is that `sum([1, 2])` is doing `sum([1,2], 0)` as `0 + 1 + 2`. So that `sum([[1], [2]], [])` is doing `[] + [1] + [2]`

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 but the reason why `sum([[1], [2]])` doesn't work is because it's trying to add `[1]` and `[2]` to 0, the default value, which is why you get the error. When you specify the `[]` as your starting value, it works fine.

Comment: @asongtoruin Right. I did not know about the second variable's function of `sum()` before, I thought `sum(1,2)` is `1+2`, and `sum(1,2,3)` is `1+2+3`, while actually `sum` can only take 2 arguments, and the second one is the base before sums up everything in the first one.

Answer (score 3):

The builtin method `sum` will use the `+` operation to sum a list of elements. Its second argument is the starting value.

By default the starting value is `0`, meaning `sum([[1], [2]])` is equivalent to `0 + [1] + [2]` which raises a `TypeError`.

To concatenate lists you want the initial value to be `[]`, an empty list. Then, `sum([[1], [2], [3]], [])` is equivalent to `[] + [1] + [2] + [3]` as desired.

### Performance

It is not recommended to use `sum` to concatenate a list of lists. Indeed, on every addition a *new* list is created. Instead you want to use a solution that traverses all lists and append the items to a new list.

```
def concat_lists(lists):
    new_list = []
    for l in lists:
        new_list.extend(l)
```

Or alternatively using `itertools`.

```
from itertools import chain

new_list = list(chain(*lists))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got the explanation from the previous answer, but the Performance part is very helpful, appreciate it.